# Scope of Questions about Marketing

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

[This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/can-anyone-recommend-a-free-website-builder) asks for recommendations for free website builders. This strikes me as off-topic. However, after thinking about it, it could also pertain to marketing. According to [this Meta question](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/should-we-allow-questions-pertaining-to-marketing-a-self-published-book), answering questions about marketing a book is on-topic.

My question: If one is asking for advice on where to find resources to build a website to market one's book, is this on or off topic? If it is on-topic, where is the line?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I've closed; IMHO this question is firmly off-topic, barring a substantial edit.

Comment: My SO senses said off-topic but I didn't want to declare it was and give the OP advice on changing it until I was sure. The fact that it insights discussion and opinions should have told me it was off-topic but many perfectly acceptable questions here have had many varying opinions.

Comment: I flagged it for the same thing. It seemed like such a potentially useful question, but it just didn't feel right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the same rule that Stack Exchange, et al, have for their scope. Substitute "writers" for "programmers":

[image]

If a writer *could* use a particular question, but it's equally useful to a dozen other professions, it's not appropriate to Writers.SE.

Comment: So, asking for a good website builder is off topic (and insights discussion and opinions). It falls to "All Careers." What if the OP asked for a website builder that tailors to book publishing? For instance, "... site builder for marketing a self-published book" or "... self-published (sci-fi|fantasy|non-fiction|thriller) book." It narrows the target to "All Writers" but it still feels off-topic since it feels like the question could pertain to any career if altered just slightly.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell: First of all, we'd have to consider whether there _are_ such services catering to writers specifically, and what those services are, and what's writer-specific about them. Not every profession _has_ web-building services tailored to it. A question "What service offers [Writing-Specific Feature X]?" might be closer on target.

Comment: All that aside, though, SE strongly discourages recommendation questions and questions whose answers will likely be a list of links. They're not much better than a Google search; voting isn't clear; and info becomes outdated very quickly.