# Are questions about sources or references for help book editing acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

*Disclaimer: English isn't my native language and I haven't studied writing or poetry at all.*

According to my [question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/how-do-i-convince-readers-to-keep-reading-poems-with-fixed-rhyme), I'm editing my poetry book, however, basically I'm a aspiring poet and my knowledges about book editing (specially for book poetry) are minimal *(zero actually)*.

Checking questions in meta.writers, I found [this one](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/should-we-allow-questions-pertaining-to-marketing-a-self-published-book) related to marketing a self-published book, but my questions is about sources or references that anyone can use for edit their self-published book.

Like the tile says, **Are questions about sources or references for help book editing acceptable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions asking for resources are on topic here. However, you're better off asking a specific question about an editing problem you have. The are not answerable and are what the Stack Exchange Q&A engine has been built to handle best.

Comment: I'll ask a new question about resources then. The specific question about editing problem will be asked once I checked the resources. Thanks.

Comment: [The question asking about resources is already generated](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/15980/references-or-tips-for-book-editing-self-published-books)

Comment: Your question would be better if you said, in the question, what you were looking for - i.e., resources that relate to editing poetry. Some people may not follow your links.

Comment: I'm trying to ask about references or tips for book editing, for the moment I need a guide or basis for edit my self-published book, a _example_ that comes in mind is: _best way of order poems, (by chapters, or with special numeration, maybe reference to other poetry books for see his structure of the book **not their poetry**), etc_ but your comment will be in a new question _since my poetry is in spanish language, I'm doubt that anyone can help me at this moment._ Thank you @Neil Fein.